# Is there a way to simulate shake on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod-touch, xcode

I am NOT talking about the simulator. I was wondering if I could simulate a shake on my actual iphone (by plugging it into computer and connected to xcode).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Given the answer by Edward, are you seeking the Shake gesture or making the phone vibrate?  I assumed shake gesture until I read him telling how to make it vibrate.

Answer (score 5):

- Open System Preferences
- Go to General > Accessibility > Assistive Touch
- Turn assistive touch on
- Then, an icon that looks like:

[image: assistive touch]

Will pop up somewhere on you screen. Tap it. Then:

- Tap device
- Tap more
- and finally tap shake

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

- Search the App Store to see if there are any apps that do this (see [Google Search](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ios%20vibrate%20app&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=LXj6U7T5DajE8gei_oD4AQ#q=ios%20vibrate%20app&rls=en&safe=off))
- Write an App that does it (see [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724980/making-the-iphone-vibrate))

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a very good answer and is not particularly helpful.